# Mensagem de Invalid syntax sem nenhum erro aparente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando renomear uma pasta que possui um conjunto de arquivos, quero retirar todos os algarismos dos nomes dos arquivos. Mas quando tento rodar o código aparece a mensagem de erro: "invalid syntax", apontando especificamente para o módulo os. Alguém sabe dizer qual a razão do erro e como posso consertar isso? Segue o código:

```
import os 
def rename_files():
    #(1) pegue os nomes dos arquivos da pasta 
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Projetos\arquivos") 
    #print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print("Curret Working Directory is "+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r"C:\Projetos\arquivos")
    #(2) para cada arquivo, renomeie o nome do arquivo
    for file_name in file_list:
        print("Old Name - "+file_name)
        print("New Name - "+file_name.translate(None, "0123456789")
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.traslate(None, "0123456789"))
    os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()
```

Comment: Pode por na pergunta a mensagem completa do erro? E como está executando esse código?

Comment: Essa é a mensagem completa do erro. Eu rodo o programa e abre uma janela com a frase "invalid syntax" Eu uso o IDLE para escrever, não sei se isso influencia em como as mensagens são mostradas.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss , usei um outro editor online e apaceu a mensagem: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 13
    os.rename(file_name, file_name.traslate(None, "0123456789"))
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está na linha 12, você não fechou o parenteses da função print:

O correto seria:

```
import os 
def rename_files():
    #(1) pegue os nomes dos arquivos da pasta 
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Projetos\arquivos") 
    #print(file_list)
    saved_path = os.getcwd()
    print("Curret Working Directory is "+saved_path)
    os.chdir(r"C:\Projetos\arquivos")
    #(2) para cada arquivo, renomeie o nome do arquivo
    for file_name in file_list:
        print("Old Name - "+file_name)
        print("New Name - "+file_name.translate(None, "0123456789"))//O erro estava aqui
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.traslate(None, "0123456789"))
    os.chdir(saved_path)
rename_files()
```

Comment: Eu fechei agora, mas apareceu outros erros. Obg por indicar.